# Como separar imagens parecidas (Pyhton / Aprendizagem de máquina)

Tags: python, inteligência-artificial, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Objetivo: Separar imagens com características iguais de uma pasta com diversas imagens

(exp: foto1, foto2, foto3, foto4, foto5 >>> foto1.Copo1 foto2.Copo2 foto3.Copo3; foto4.Cachorro1,foto5.Cachorro2...)

Gostaria de uma luz no assunto, mas na parte que eu estudei, acredito que seria algo no estilo : Aprendizagem de máquina -> Não supervisionada -> Agrupamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta é muito genérica, não há como responder especificamente.

Uma coisa que você pode fazer é usar k-means para clusterizar por algum critério de semelhança.  Você decide o critério:
1) Pode clusterizar por cor, por exemplo;
2) Se as imagens são normalizadas, você pode usar SIFT e definir como critério quantos keypoints são inliers.

Estou assumindo que você não tem nenhuma informação de categoria das imagens, uma vez que você mencionou aprendizado não-supervisionado. Se tiver qualquer informação de categoria, os resultados são melhores.

Comment: a questão é bem ampla, mas infelizmente n dá para dividir por cor. 
O problema: tenho +7000 imagens, e tenho q separar elas por semelhança , como por exemplo, separar todas as imagens que contem um poste.

Comment: Eu tentei explicitar melhor o que queria dizer.

Comment: Obrigado @fredguth , vou dar uma estudada nesse caminho.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente eu aconselharia a reduzir as dimensões dessas imagens.
Pois se for aplicar um K-means pode acontecer o problema de Course Of dimensionality que faz com algoritmos que usam distâncias entre um ponto e outro percam precisão.
Porem não digo literalmente reduzir o tamanho da imagem mas sim utilizar um PCA ou SVD para isso pois irá conservar informações relevantes da imagem.

Existem outras formas de clusters como hierarchical clustering e Autoencouders que podem ser uteis também.

Outro ponto importante é a memória necessária para lidar com essa quantidade de imagens. dependendo do algoritmo e da quantidade de memoria de seu computador você pode trava-lo.

Existem métodos mais diretos como comparação de pedações da imagem A com a imagem B.(mas não acredito que seja muito bom.)

Emfim existem várias formas de se fazer esse tipo de clusterização.